# Completely recreate an amazon free-tier instance due to having a new key-pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, hosting

I launched a **free-tier amazon** instance ec2 with some key-pair. Then I deleted this key-pair and created a new one. The instance kept running with the first (deleted) key-pair. I wanted to re-create the instance but the only thing what I could do was terminating it. So I have a terminated instance with the deleted key-pair and the new key-pair which is not used.

Ideally, I'd like to go back to square one and create a new instance and use the existing key-pair (or create one more, that doesn't matter). How can I do this?

Comment: What is holding you back from creating a new instance and use the existing key-pair that you have? There does not seem to be a problem at all.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer, can I create as many new instances as I want when I'm on free-tier?

Comment: so, the free tier means, you can have 750 hrs per month of `t1.micro` type of instances. How you reach this limit is upto you. You can run 1 instance og `t1.micro` type for 750 hrs per month or running 75 instances of `t1.micro` type for 10 hrs each per month. Also this free tier dies after you complete 1 year and then you have to pay even for running `t1.micro` instnaces.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. If you have found it helpful and think it resolves your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, the free tier means, you can have 750 hrs per month of `t1.micro` type of instances. How you reach this limit is upto you. You can run 1 instance of `t1.micro` type for 750 hrs per month or running 75 instances of `t1.micro` type for 10 hrs each per month. Also this free tier dies after you complete 1 year and then you have to pay even for running `t1.micro` instnaces.

Refer:

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/

**UPDATE:**

Check the screen shot below (this was taken from http://aws.amazon.com/free/)

[image]

So...

1. Free Tier does not have PostGreSQL RDS included. It does have MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle.
2. So, your only other option remains is to have an EC2 instance of t1.micro type and install configure PostgreSQL on it just the way you would do it on any other server. However, I really doubt the performance of this instance running PostGReSQL on a t1.micro type.

Comment: by the way, on free tier I want to use Postgresql. Do I have to install it myself as if it were my local machine or do they they their own one? If the second case, is it still free? I didn't find any info about it (I'm using Linux).

Comment: thanks. are you sure they don't have postgresql on free tier? I just set up one postgresql instance. Well, I'm still unsure whether it's free or not, but it seems to be free.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/ , this link generalize the free RDS usage but does not specifically says about PostgreSQL. So , sounds like it is free but I am not sure.

Comment: and it doesn't specifically say about mysql either, however.